# How can I divide the screen to these divs in css?

Tags: html, css

Just how can I make my page look like this:
[image]

When the left, and right (the upper divs

When A and B's height is unknown (well, the one who has most content will decide on how down below C is)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AHk78/

HTML

```
<div id="upleft"></div>
<div id="upright"></div>
<div id="below"></div>​
```

CSS

```
#upleft { width:100px; height: 500px; background:red; float:left; }
#upright { width:300px; height:200px; background:blue; float:left }
#below { height:300px; width:100%; background:green; clear:both }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would make the sections percentages, that way you get these proportions no matter what screen size the user has.

## CSS

> ```
> #sectionA
> {
>    float:left;
>    width: 20%;
> }
> #sectionB
> {
>    float:left;
>    width: 80%;
> }
>
> #sectionB
> {
>    clear:both;
>    width: 100%;
> }
> ```

## HTML

> ```
> <div id="sectionA"></div>
> <div id="sectionB"></div>
> <div id="sectionC"></div>
> ```

Comment: cheers for the edit...that's what I get for copying and pasting :P

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#divA
{
   float:left;
   width: <width of div A>;
}
#divB
{
   float:left;
   width: <width of div B>;
}

#divC
{
   clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
<div id="divC"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it inline with following example for right alignment:

```
<div style="width:30%;float:right"><!--write your required tags--></div>
```

Here width and float varies depending on the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

A
float: left

B
float: left;

C
clear: both;

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make this simply as like this

**Css**

```
#left { 
    width:100px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    min-height:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}

#bottom{
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    clear:both;
}
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>​
```

Live demo [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/AHk78/2/) http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/AHk78/2/