# divide the page in three parts using div tag

Tags: html, layout

I am trying to get the below layout for more than 1.5 hours but still can't get the right solution.

well if there are any duplicates then forgivve me for asking this question.

I want to have a layout like below diagram using div tag:

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|                                            |                                                                                                                     |
|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

I know how to do it using table tag.

Comment: any code that you tried would be useful. can you use twitter bootstrap?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986145/how-can-i-divide-the-screen-to-these-divs-in-css

Comment: Here is a fiddle for that last question: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/U9Z2Z/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is exact [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHk78/52/) or [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/uwodav/1/edit)

Make **CSS** as

```
#upleft { 
   width:100px; 
   height: 300px; 
   background:red; float:left; 
}

#upright { 
   width:300px; 
   height:200px; 
   background:blue; 
   float:left
}
#below { 
   height:300px; 
   width:400px; 
   background:green 
}
```

And in **HTML**

```
<div id="upleft"></div>
<div id="upright"></div>
<div id="below"></div>
```

Comment: Breaks on my wide screen (linux, using latest chromium stable), the green div goes below all divs on me.

Comment: @ Naveen ,  Yup, It's fixed now

Comment: @Arda Is it okay for you?

Comment: it's fixed for me ineded

Answer (score 7):

`float:left` is your friend

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div {
    display: block;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
}

#first {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#second {
    float:left;
    width: 67%;
    height: 30%;
    background: green;
}

#third {
    float:left;
    width: 67%;
    height: 70%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vkmq3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css and html code:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
  float:left;
  width:27%;
  height: 25em;
  margin:1px .2em 1px 1px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#content {
  margin:1px .2em 1px 28%;
}
#cnt1 {
  position;relative;
  margin:.3em 2px;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#cnt2 {
  position;relative;
  margin:.3em 2px;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left side</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="cnt1">Up</div>
  <div id="cnt2">Down</div>
</div>
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

Comment: Is `position;relative;` really required? Also there's a typo there.